# node.js - Receiving no data with cross origin access

Tags: node.js, http, cors

I've got 2 servers, 1 using nodejs and another one using gulp-webserver.

The node.js server uses a users.json file and displays them.

```
var express     =   require("express");
var app         =   express();
var bodyParser  =   require("body-parser");
var router      =   express.Router();
var cors        = require('cors')
var fs          = require("fs");
app.use(cors());
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({"extended" : false}));

app.get('/listUsers', function (req, res) {
   fs.readFile( __dirname + "/" + "users.json", 'utf8', function (err, data) {
       console.log( data );
       res.end( data );
   });
})

var server = app.listen(8081, function () {

  var host = server.address().address
  var port = server.address().port

  console.log("Example app listening at http://%s:%s", host, port)

})
```

user.json:

```
 {
   "user1" : {
      "name" : "mahesh",
      "password" : "password1",
      "profession" : "teacher",
      "id": 1
   },
   "user2" : {
      "name" : "suresh",
      "password" : "password2",
      "profession" : "librarian",
      "id": 2
   },
   "user3" : {
      "name" : "ramesh",
      "password" : "password3",
      "profession" : "clerk",
      "id": 3
   }
}
```

Now I want to call that data using a get method and, store it into a variable and then display it using a primeng-datatable.

Therefore I have a data.service:

```
import { Injectable }    from '@angular/core';
import { Headers, Http } from '@angular/http';
import { Data } from './data';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/toPromise';

@Injectable()
export class DataService {

    constructor(private http : Http) {

    }

    getData(){
    return this.http.get('http://localhost:8081/listUsers')
               .toPromise()
                    .then(res => <Data[]> res.json().data)
                    .then(data => { return data; });

               ;}
}
```

I'm calling this one onInit within my datacomponent:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Data } from './data';
import {DataTable} from 'primeng/primeng';
import {Column} from 'primeng/primeng';
import { Headers, Http } from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/toPromise';
import { DataService } from './data.service'

@Component({
    selector: 'my-datatbl',
    templateUrl: 'dist/data.component.html',
    directives: [DataTable, Column], 
    providers: [DataService]
})

export class DataComponent {
datatbl: Data[];
    constructor(private dataservice : DataService) {

    }




    ngOnInit(){


    this.dataservice.getData().then(datatbl => this.datatbl = datatbl)
    console.log(this.datatbl)
```

consolelog shows undefined.

I don't know whta's wrong, but as I'm an absolute newbe, my first question is:
Is this even possible?

This is just for testing purposes, as I'm getting into REST apis. I dont want to use mongodb or any other database service at this stage, although I might do it, if this would be the only way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I solved it myself.
The problem was, that my response was referring to a .data property of my users.json, which obviously doesn't exist. So I simply changed my users.json to

```
   {   "data": [
   {
      "name" : "mahesh",
      "password" : "password1",
      "profession" : "teacher",
      "id": 1
   },
  {
      "name" : "suresh",
      "password" : "password2",
      "profession" : "librarian",
      "id": 2
   },
    {
      "name" : "ramesh",
      "password" : "password3",
      "profession" : "clerk",
      "id": 3
   }
]
}
```

and now everything just works fine.